# DataBinding visibility depending on a list size

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am having an object which is using in data binding as a variable.

```
public class Company {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Employee> employees;
    private List<Room> rooms;
}


<data>
     <variable
         name="item"
         type="com.blablabla.model.entity.Company"/>

</data>
```

Want to change visibility of a view depending on a list size (employees), so if the list is null or empty - visibility is GONE, otherwise it is VISIBLE.

What have I tried so far:
1) Setting the visibility directly:

```
  android:visibility="@{item.employees.size() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

In fact visibility is always GONE.

Of course I imported

```
<import type="android.view.View"/>
```

2) Using BindingConverter:

```
@BindingConversion
    public static int convertCollectionToVisibility(Collection collection) {
        Log.d(TAG, "collection: " + (collection == null ? "null" : collection.size()));
        return collection == null || collection.isEmpty() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
    }
```

and then in layout:

```
android:visibility="@{item.employees}"
```

Here the log shows, that collection is always null.
But it is definitely not

```
Company company = new Company(1, "Company 1");
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        employees.add(new Employee(i, "Jack", "Floyd"));
        company.setEmployees(employees);
mBinding.setItem(company);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could use an `ObservableInt listVisibility = new ObservableInt(View.GONE);` and set it to `listVisibility .set(list.size() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE)`. In `xml`: `android:visibility="@{listVisibility}"`.   I think you need to update the `listVisibility` whenever your `List` changes, execpt when you use an `ObservableList` or something like that.

Comment: thanks. I think it is  possible solution, but I wonder why I can not do it without observables

Comment: I think it is even better using a `ObservableInt` because adding more conditions is really easy and you are keeping your `xml` files clean of business logic.

Comment: Have you tried to expect a `List` in your `BindingConversion`? Is it also null?

Comment: Yes, with the list it is the same

Comment: I am kind of curios right now - have you tried a `Company` `BindingConversion`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense as I need to figure out visibility for the employees list, rooms list etc. And adding additional attribute will be kind of ugly I think

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem with [these files](https://gist.github.com/amylinn/dd0a2bda5bc3f8de721299af80cbc165), but I am not able to. My `BindingConversion` with `List` and with `Collection` works perfectly. Does your other binding stuff work?

Comment: Did you set the correct item to the binding?

Comment: Cool thanks! In my case it still doesn't work. Now will compare and try to figure out

Comment: thanks a lot for help! Compared with your code and figured out that was setting a wrong variable. You can post an answer so I can accept it

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. :)

Comment: ObservableInt worked for me and it eliminated the warning at compile time. I was using Observable<Integer> which wasn't the type for my widget visibility property and so I was getting a warning about needing to use safeUnbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After recreating a [sample program](https://gist.github.com/amylinn/dd0a2bda5bc3f8de721299af80cbc165) OP found out, that he was setting a wrong variable.

Sample:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding binding = 
                DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        Company company1 = new Company();
        Company company2 = new Company();

        ArrayList<String> employee2 = new ArrayList<>();
        employee2.add("First");
        company2.setEmployees(employee2);

        binding.setCompany1(company1);
        binding.setCompany2(company2);
    }

    @BindingConversion
    public static int listToVisibility(List list) {
        //Also works with Collection
        return (list == null || list.isEmpty()) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE;
    }
}
```

Xml:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="company1"
            type="com.may.amy.bindingconversiontest.Company" />
        <variable
            name="company2"
            type="com.may.amy.bindingconversiontest.Company" />
    </data>
    <TextView
        android:text="Company1 has employees"
        android:visibility="@{company1.employees}"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Company2 has employees"
        android:visibility="@{company2.employees}"/>
</layout>
```

My preferred solution to the "visibility problem" is to use

```
ObservableInt listVisibility = new ObservableInt(View.GONE);
```

in my `ViewModel`.

```
boolean visible = list.size() > 0 || showHeaderIfEmpty; 
listVisibility .set(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

The advantage is that my condition can easily depend on many factors instead of only the list size.

In xml:

```
android:visibility="@{listVisibility}"
```

Of course this may need to be updated, or used with an `ObservableList`.

Answer (score 12):

I just faced the same problem and setting visibility directly by `item.employees.size` (without parentheses) worked for me like a charm.

`android:visibility="@{item.employees.size > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"`

Answer (score 3):

Let's call a new file "BindingAdapters", since possibly you will be using it on other places.

```
object BindingAdapters {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("visibleGone")
    fun showHide(view: View, show: Boolean) {
        view.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

on the XML you just have to do the following:

```
app:visibleGone="@{viewModel.list.isNotEmpty()}"
```

Comment: Somehow, this does not seems to work for me ; I've been wondering for hours now why exactly

Comment: You can try something simple as: `app:visibleGone="true"` in the xml to check if maybe it's the boolean that is not correct. In addition you may wrap your boolean condition with `app:visibleGone="@{safeUnbox(viewModel.list.isNotEmpty())}"`. You need to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` at the top of your xml as well, which is something that Android Studio should've already suggested.

Comment: my `list` in this case is wrapped on a `LiveData` object inside `viewModel`. Would that be a problem? 'cause that's the only thing I can think of that might be triggering this..

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you well, but you should observe live datas from a fragment/activity, and when you get the change, update the viewModel list. If that doesn't work by its own, try updating the viewmodel reference from the xml as well. Something like: `binding.viewModel = yourViewModel ` after updating the list of elements inside the viewmodel

Answer (score 3):

I used **empty** as below and it worked for me:

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.data.empty ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

Please let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to do accessing the list directly from `ViewModel` like:

```
app:visibleGone="@{viewModel.list.isNotEmpty()}"
```

However, what solved my problem was:

1. Create a `boolean` type on xml:

```
<data>
...
  <variable
    name="hasItens"
    type="boolean" />
...
</data
```

2. Bind `hasItens` on adapter's update:

```
vm.list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { list ->
            container.hasItens = !list.isNullOrEmpty()
            adapter.submitList(builtDates)
}
```

3. Create your `BindAdapter`:

```
@BindingAdapter("isGone")
fun bindIsGone(view: View, isGone: Boolean) {
    view.visibility = if (isGone) {
        View.GONE
    } else {
        View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

4. Set visibility on your `View``

```
<RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recyclerId"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  app:isGone="@{!hasItens}" />
```